# "I can't get the message across."

Tags: phrases

What are some other ways to say, "I can't get the message across?" This is explaining a situation where someone doesn't communicate what they're thinking, or they try to communicate what they're thinking, but the recipient doesn't understand what what the speaker wants them to understand.

I'm looking for words to replace "get the message across", not an entirely different phrase.

Comment: Interestingly we seem to have lots of single-word ways of referencing the message *receiver* side of things. He can get, see, understand, grasp, follow, etc., all of which are trivially negated to indicate that he *didn't* (i.e. - the communication failed). But negating the verb used for the message *sender* (didn't tell, didn't explain, etc.) usually means he did nothing, rather than tried and failed to get the message across.

Comment: How about: "Mmmf! Mmmmf! Uh, mmmmf!" [Point to tape on mouth]

Comment: Can you not **frigging** understand me !!!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm not coming/getting through.
- I'm not being clear.
- We're talking at cross purposes.

Answer (score 2):

How about "I can't put it into words?"

Answer (score 1):

I can't make myself understood?

Answer (score 1):

*I fail to convey it.*

Looks like you answered this question with your [next one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/19664/5822). Or no?

Also, I thought of some phrases which are not limited to, but have particular resonance in African-American vernacular. These "convey" *get the message across*:

- Make it plain.
- Make it real.
- Break it down.