# "fail to convey it"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Does "I fail to convey it" mean "I know but I don't explain it" or does it mean "I know and I try to explain it, but not well enough for people to understand it" or can it mean both?

What's another way to say, "I fail to convey it?"

Answer (score 3):

> I know and I try to explain it, but
>   not well enough for people to
>   understand it.

Is the meaning of "I fail to convey it". Which happens unintentionally, possible reasons could be that:

- Someone uses to many technical terms
- Inappropriate explanation or media to communicate an idea.

Some examples of usage:

- Words fail to convey the total value of yoga. It has to be experienced.
- [How images fail to convey war's horror](http://articles.latimes.com/2003/mar/16/books/bk-ascherson16)

Comment: Could it also mean, "I want to explain it, but for some reason I don't even try."

Comment: @language hacker I think only in contexts like, a politician says something in response to a question but is actually avoids (intentionally) to give a concrete answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well both.

IMO, "I fail to convey it" is an incomplete sentence and has the wrong tense too, it needs context on what the *it* is.

for example in these two sentences:

"I failed to convey *your message correctly*"

"I would fail to convey *the information in time*"

*convey* by itself means "to transport or communicate"

In such a case "fail to convey" can mean

a) I did not transport or communicate the message at all.

e.g: If I *failed to convey* a message to someone because I forgot or could not get time to or just did not feel like it.

b) Communicated incorrectly due to lack of understanding or clarity.

e.g: A translated work *fails to convey* the meaning of the original.